# Как добавить значения данных переменной над столбцами Barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]На данной диаграмме я хотела бы получить количество ответивших на самих столбцах.Наподобие этого[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это образец, моя диаграмма выглядит без этих значений.

Answer (score 2):

для добавления надписей на график можно использовать [функцию `geom_text()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html).

возьмём для примера набор данных `mpg` и нарисуем разбивку по переменной `class`:

```
> ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar()
```

[image: исходный график]

чтобы надпись содержала количество наблюдений (`count`), функции `geom_text()` надо передать такие параметры:

```
> ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar()
  + geom_text(stat= "count", aes(y = ..count.., label = ..count..))
```

[image: первая попытка]

уже практически то, что нужно. только вот надписи сливаются со столбиками и надо бы выводить их не вровень с верхним краем столбика, а немного выше. для этого подойдёт параметр `vjust` (видимо, «vertical adjust»):

```
> ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar()
  + geom_text(stat= "count", aes(y = ..count.., label = ..count..), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image: выравнивамем надпись по вертикали]

теперь, вроде, всё как надо.

---

как вариант — можно не сдвигать надписи, а **выделить** их, заменив функцию `geom_text()` на `geom_label()`:

```
> ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar()
  + geom_label(stat= "count", aes(y = ..count.., label = ..count..))
```

[image: используем geom_label()]

на мой взгляд — даже симпатичнее получилось.

---

p.s. ещё вместо `vjust` можно сразу увеличить вертикальную позицию. например, на единицу:

```
> ggplot(…) + … + geom_text(…, aes(y = ..count.. + 1, …))
```

Comment: Возникает проблемка, не находит пакет ggplot, зато находит ggplot2. попробовала через него, все равно цифры не ставит на столбцах. пробовала и первый вариант и второй(с label).

Comment: пакет называется `ggplot2`. функция называтся `ggplot()`. единственная приходящая в голову гипотеза: слишком старые версии. я готовил пример с `R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo"`. [версия пакета](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11103189/4827341) `ggplot2` — 3.1.0

Comment: у вас не получается аналог приведённой картинки именно с примером (`ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar() + geom_label(stat= "count", aes(y = ..count.., label = ..count..))`) или с вашими данными?

Comment: все,разобралась,оказывается из за того что плюсик на другую строку переносила, в точности как в Вашем примере. Оставила плюс на первой строке и надписи сразу появились. Спасибо за помощь!